# programmatically extract tar.gz in a single step (on windows with 7zip)

Tags: archiving, script, tar, 7-zip, gzip

**PROBLEM:** I would like to be able to extract tar.gz files in a single step. This makes my question *almost*  identical to this one: [stackoverflow question for tar-gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651018/opening-a-tar-gz-file-with-a-single-command).

My question is *almost* the same, but not the same, because I would like to do this on windows using 7zip command-line (or something similar) inside a bat file or ruby/perl/python script.

**QUESTION:** This seemingly simple task is proving to be more involved than the first appearance would make it out to be. Does anyone have a script that does this already?

Comment: If it's so similar to that question, doesn't this belong on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I already asked there, but someone on stackoverflow voted to move it here, so i asked here in case it got erased. There's always the "grey area" questions that could be on both sites, this seems like one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [GnuWin32 ports of gzip and tar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) are what you need (scroll down)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like adding a temporary .tgz extension?

```
MOVE %1 %1.tgz
7z x %1.tgz
MOVE %1.tgz %1
```

I might be wrong, but I believe 7zip will unzip tgz files all at once (instead of with tar.gz files).

Answer (score 0):

Try the tartool utility
http://tartool.codeplex.com/

I was frustrated by the lack of a cmd line utility for such a simple task and created it for this exact reason.

The code is open source and uses SharpZipLib library.